# When I use Ctrl-C to terminate the input , the output is reduced in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++

```
//Program to terminate the input by ctrl-c    
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    string word;

    while (cin >> word)
        vec.push_back(word);

    cout << endl << endl;
    auto beg = vec.begin();
    while (beg != vec.end())
    {
        //to print the vector
        cout << *beg << endl;
        beg++;
    }
}
```

When in press control-c to terminate the input stream of...

```
ankur
anshu
singh
ankit
ashuto
ashu
```

I get...

```
ankur
anshu
si^CPress any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: just for curiosity, what else did you expect to happen?

Comment: Ctrl+C terminates the program, not the input.  Use Ctrl+Z instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a terminal (a.k.a. command line), `Ctrl+C` kills the program immediately. It doesn't wait for anything or anyone. Thus, your program is literally stopping in the middle of execution, so what it does and doesn't do is a total crapshoot.

In some cases, you may actually want `Ctrl+D` (Linux/Unix) or `Ctrl+Z` (Windows), which signifies "end of document". That may be interpreted as "end of input" without otherwise interrupting the program. However, your results may vary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: You're welcome. If it solves your problem, don't forget to click the green checkbox to accept it. Thanks!